# Integrals Involving The Modulus Function.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Let $$I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\pi + 4x^5}{1-sin(|x|+\frac{\pi}{6})}$$

I need to compute $I$.

It does look like a standard integral except for the fact that $x$ is in the modulus. Since the limits are of the form $-a$ to $a$, I can replace $x$ with $-x$ in the integral.

The problem arises with the modulus function. Since it is not differentiable wherever the modulus reaches zero, I have to divide the integral by taking two separate cases - one as the function goes from $-a$ to $0$ and another from $0$ to $a$ to get rid of the modulus.

Of course, solving the integral without the modulus is tricky itself, but how do you go about integrals with a modular functions? Is case work a must?

Comment: Yes taking cases is one way to avoid the modulus function. The other case is trying to eliminate the modulus itself by arguing that its input is always positive eg. $$|x^2| = x^2$$

Comment: how would you go about solving the integral though?

Comment: Take cases for values of $x$ where the function goes negative and positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Use $I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$I+I=\int_a^b\{f(x)+f(a+b-x)\}\ dx$

Then  divide the integral range from $-\pi/6,0;0;\pi/6$

and use $|x|=+x$ if $x\ge0$  and $=-x$ if $x\le0$